# What are the St. Patrick's day artifacts?

Tags: temple-run-2

I just realized there was a St. Patricks's day event and got an "Emerald Idol" for that.  It looks like the same as the Christmas and Valentines events- 5 themed artifacts and then the reward is some kind of hat.

What are the artifacts for the St. Patrick's event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was lucky and found them all quickly without much repeating.  They are

- Rainbow
- Pot O' Gold
- Leprechaun Boots
- Four Leaf Clover
- Emerald Idol (ha ha!)

The reward is another hat, a green Leprechaun-type one.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pot of gold, leprechaun shoes, a rainbow, the emerald idol, and another that I haven't found yet.